# Assign each column of grid view to different width in metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm developing metro app using C# and XAML, I'm stuck with grid view that my grid view consist of multiple grids by default grid view assigns equal width to all grids,But i wanna give different width for each grid.example code is below

```
<GridView x:Name="ObjGridView">
            <Grid Background="Black" Height="400" Width="464">

            </Grid>
            <Grid Background="Blue" Height="400" Width="464">

            </Grid>
            <Grid Background="Blue" Height="400" Width="464">

            </Grid>
         <!--Up to n Grids-->
</GridView>
```

So,Is there any way to give width for grids manually or can change the column width of grid view. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can solve your problem:

[How To: Create a Variable Sized Grouped GridView (like the store)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/966aa897-1413-46f0-bef7-663de36f9423)

[Discussion about this on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/21d227cf-feec-4c32-a01e-257ac1e81643/)